# pol2cart matlab doesn't provide [X Y]

Tags: function, matlab

The `pol2cart` function in matlab should convert an array of angles and distances to a list of `[X Y]` positions. When I do the following commands I get this:

```
a1 = [1 2 3 4 5]';
a2 = [6 7 8 9 10]';
pol2cart(a1, a2)

ans =

 3.2418
-2.9130
-7.9199
-5.8828
 2.8366
```

reading the information in `help pol2cart` seems to indicate that i should get an array of X Y values which should be `5x2` not `5x1` ?

Comment: Didn't see your comment before I added my answer. But whenever you find the answer to your own question before anyone else does, feel free to add the answer yourself. It will help others with the same question just as much reading a correct answer from the asker than from someone else :)

Comment: @ThijsW I know, but it gives a chance for someone else, like yourself to get some reputation points. Good work!

Comment: Very kind of you, sir! ;)  I'm a long time reader, but only recently started answering questions too (and I must say, SO is very addictive!) :)

Comment: @ThijsW It is, but thank you for helping with my questions.

Comment: @ThijsW You are on a roll how about a hand with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995643/change-legend-diagram-in-matlab) one.

Comment: I added an answer and even did it without using a loop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function like this:

```
[X,Y] = pol2cart(a1, a2);
```

This will give you two vectors: `X` and `Y`.