# Change Legend diagram in matlab

Tags: matlab, figure

I have some code that basically does this:

```
for i = 1:length(ReliabilityStruct)
    if (FailureFlags(i) == 0) 
        plot(X(i), Y(i), '.b');
    elseif (FailureFlags(i) == 1)
        plot(X(i), Y(i), 'or');
    elseif (FailureFlags(i) == 2)
        plot(X(i), Y(i), 'og');
    elseif (FailureFlags(i) == 3)
        plot(X(i), Y(i), 'ok');
    else
        fprintf('\nUnknown Flag, check Data\n')
        return
    end
end
drawnow;
legend('Recovery', '1', '2', '3');
```

So my aim is to make a graph that has different symbols for different flags. See below:

[image]

As you can see, the Legend doesn't exactly fit the data. How can you change each of the legend entries to fix this up? Alternatively, is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use something like this (added bonus is that you avoid loops!):

```
ind = FailureFlags==0;
plot(X(ind), Y(ind), '.b');

ind = FailureFlags==1;
plot(X(ind), Y(ind), 'or');

ind = FailureFlags==2;
plot(X(ind), Y(ind), 'og');

ind = FailureFlags==3;
plot(X(ind), Y(ind), 'ok');

legend('Recovery', '1', '2', '3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. In your loop make an assignment for each plot as follows:

```
 p1=plot(X(i), Y(i), '.b');
elseif (FailureFlags(i) == 1)
 p2=plot(X(i), Y(i), 'or');
elseif (FailureFlags(i) == 2)
 p3=plot(X(i), Y(i), 'og');
elseif (FailureFlags(i) == 3)
 p4=plot(X(i), Y(i), 'ok');
```

Then you can use legend for the specific things:

```
legend([p1 p2],'stuff','morestuff')
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can refer to the usage for any function using `help` command. For your case, the `help legend` will give you usage examples like following.

```
legend(H,string1,string2,string3, ...) puts a legend on the plot
containing the handles in the vector H using the specified strings as
labels for the corresponding handles.
```

Thus, you can get the plot handler by assign the plot to a variable, such as `p1=plot(X(i), Y(i), '.b');`. And then draw the legend by invoke the command with handlers as first parameter, like `legend([p1], 'something')`.